# Why isn't there an orElse method on PartialFunction that accepts a total function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Why is there no method with following signature on class `PartialFunction[A, B]`?

```
def orElse[A1 <: A, B1 >: B](that: A1 => B1): A1 => B1
```

Is there some logical reason behind the absence of this method, or was it a mere oversight?

Answer (score 10):

1. Because it's trivial to achieve the same by lifting the partial function

   `partialFunc.lift(arg) getOrElse (totalFunc(arg))`
2. Because Scala, generally, tries to avoid overloading
3. Because nobody thought to add it, and it's probably not been needed so far
4. Because each and every method added to the standard library incurs an ever-growing cost in terms of downstream maintainence

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer. Replying to your bullets... 1) That's not very compositional, and makes me mention and repeat `arg`. Also if we use triviality of implementation as an argument, then Scala stdlib would have to stripped to almost half its current size. :-) 2) Fair point. 3) I needed it couple of times in last three days. 4) This is a trivial method to add (as you demonstrated). I don't think it'd add any noticeable maintenance overhead.

Comment: @missingfaktor Can't you do `(pf.lift <*> f) { _ getOrElse _ } apply arg` or something similar?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: Yes, I could do it that way, but It's still too verbose (and cryptic) for my taste.

Comment: Also it wouldn't be lazy: that is `f(arg)` would be evaluated even if `pf isDefinedAt arg` was true

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

```
scala> object O {
     |   def f(g: Int => Int) = g(1)
     |   def f(g: PartialFunction[Int, Int]) = g(2).toString
     | }
defined module O

scala> O f { _ * 1 }
res3: Int = 1
```

So, how do you chain partial functions now? Or, in other words, if the overload you describe was in the library, and I wrote this:

```
type PF = PartialFunction[Any, Int]
val pf1: PF = { case n: Int => n }
val pf2: PF = pf1 orElse { case x: String => x.length }
val pf3: PF = pf2 orElse { case d: Double => d.toInt }
```

I'd get an error message on `pf2` because of the ambiguity of the type. If, instead, I write:

```
val pf2 = pf1 orElse ((_: Any) match { case x: String => x.length })
val pf3 = pf2 orElse ((_: Any) match { case d: Double => d.toInt })
```

Then I get an error on `pf3`, because `pf2` will be a `Function1`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. :( Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I now understand your point. I don't much care about the name. They could have added it under some other name.

Comment: @missingfaktor Ah, ok. I suggest `otherwise`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears there isn't any good reason for the absence of these functions in the standard library, other than oversight or maybe nobody needs these as often as to have them in standard library.

I have defined an implicit conversion from `A => B` to `PartialFunction[A, B]` which seems to take care of this and other similar cases, and doesn't lead to adverse effects.

```
scala> implicit def fToPf[A, B](f: A => B) = new PartialFunction[A, B] {
     |   def isDefinedAt(a: A) = true
     |   def apply(a: A) = f(a)
     | }
fToPf: [A, B](f: A => B)java.lang.Object with PartialFunction[A,B]
```